# How to detect if a QString is made up of all numeric characters?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

What is the best way to tell if a `QString` is made up of just numbers?

There doesn't appear to be a convenience function in the `QString` library.

Do I have to iterate over every character, one at a time, or is there a more elegant way that I haven't thought of?

Comment: What is your definition of "more elegant"? You surely have to look at every character in one or another way, no matter if hidden behind some function or in a custom loop.

Comment: @Wes. If I can give you an advice, it will be to take 1 or 2 solid days to learn regular expressions. Their syntax is pretty much the same in all languages. I noticed that some of your questions are similar to this one. When you will possess the power of regexp, you will be able to do some powerful stuff you didn't think about first. Just saying.

Comment: Yes, I think this would be a good idea too.  I just came across them recently.  I think I need practice.  Good idea UmNyobe.  Thanks!

Comment: @UmNyobe I agree with you, i just spent them

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You could use a [regular expression](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qregexp.html), like this:

```
QRegExp re("\\d*");  // a digit (\d), zero or more times (*)
if (re.exactMatch(somestr))
   qDebug() << "all digits";
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Question though: Why is it "\\d*" and not just "\d*"  ?

Comment: Because when you write a string in C, \ has special meaning. For example `"\n"` is a newline, not a backslash character followed by the letter "n". If you really want a literal backslash character, you have to write \\.

Comment: `^` and `$` not needed because of exactMatch
and watch out for signs!
Then: `[-+]?[0-9]*`

Comment: @AdUki A dash is not a numeric character, so that renders the test incorrect.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb Incorrect. The square brackets signify a character class, the dash signifies 'in the range'. So: a character in the range of 0 to 9.

Comment: @JBE don't understand. What range does "-+" signify?

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb `[-+]` matches '+' or '-' literally. The '-' is not placed within any characters. Try for yourself at [Regex101.com](https://regex101.com/) and learn more at [Perl.org](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html). See _The Basics_  (QRegExp is based on Perlre).

Comment: @JBED isn't that what I said? How can a numeric character consist of two characters? "-1" is not a character. PS I would recommend QReguparExpression instead. The other one is deprecated, I think

Comment: I'm not really following you. See my comment at 15:12. There is no other way of explaining it. If you really don't understand I recommend reading the linked Perl document above.

Answer (score 31):

[`QString::​toInt`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#toInt)  Is what you looking for .

```
int QString::​toInt(bool * ok = 0, int base = 10) const
```

> Returns the string converted to an int using base base, which is 10 by default and must be between 2 and 36, or 0. Returns 0 if the conversion fails. If a conversion error occurs, *ok is set to false; otherwise *ok is set to true.

Example :

```
QString str = "FF";
bool ok;
int hex = str.toInt(&ok, 16);       // hex == 255, ok == true
int dec = str.toInt(&ok, 10);       // dec == 0, ok == false
```

Comment: It works only for numbers less than maximum integer value 2,147,483,647

Comment: what if the number is 0 ? it will return 0 and you will think that the conversion failed while it is not true.

Comment: @Nulik in this case you should assert against `ok`, which will be set to `true`.

Comment: Regarding the `toInt` magnitude limit - note that `QByteArray` has `toULongLong( &ok )`, and other functions like this.

Answer (score 5):

we can iterate over every character like this code:

```
QString example = "12345abcd";
for (int i =0;i<example.size();i++)
{
    if (example[i].isDigit()) // to check if it is number!! 
        // do something
    else if (example[i].isLetter()) // to check if it is alphabet !!
        // do something
}
```